# Syncfusion community licence is not working with syncfusion file manager

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

When we use "Essential Studio Enterprise Edition - Community license" it doesn't work with synfusion file manager,
It was working previously

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We suspect that the issue may occur due to the following reasons.

Reason 1:  Due to duplicate packages installed in your application. Follow the below steps to resolve this issue;

- Delete the @Syncfusion folder from node_modules and the
  package-lock.json file from the root folder.
- Clear npm cache file at your end.
- Update packages to the same major version. For example, if your
  utilizing version like (i.e. v21.1.XX) use the same version for all
  the Syncfusion components in the package.json file.
- Run the `npm install` command to install the node_modules.

Reason 2:  If Syncfusion components are used with Cap Symbol (^) in the package.json file there is a possibility of license banner appearing even after registering the license and this is one of the cases of license validation. So, we are suggesting you to use the Tilde (~) symbol instead of Cap (^) symbol and follow the below steps to resolve this issue.

- Delete the @Syncfusion folder from node_modules and the
  package-lock.json file from the root folder.
- Clear npm cache at your end.
- Remove the cap (^) symbol before the version number and use the
  mentioned symbol Tilde (~) before the version number like
  ("@syncfusion/ej2-filemanager": "~21.X.XX").
- Run the "npm install” command to install the packages.